# 98% notes hit, 9 note streak, lots of notes go clunk

Tags: xbox-360, guitar-hero

I've been playing co-op Guitar Hero 3 on my Xbox 360 recently and have noticed something a bit odd.

I have two guitar controllers, the Les Paul that came with Guitar Hero 3 and the Xplorer that came with Guitar Hero 2.  The Xplorer always seems to perform worse, no matter who is playing it.  A lot of the time, when you to hit a note the flame graphic on the note shows but the "clunk" sound for missing a note plays as well.

I just did an experiment with the two guitars in single player.  Same song, same difficulty.  With the Les Paul I got 99%, 200+ note streak and only missed three notes.  With the Xplorer I got 98%, 9 note max streak and only missed four notes.  A lot of notes went clunk, yet the game was clearly registering them as being hit!

How is this possible?  What on earth is going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like the bad guitar is registering extra notes, and the clunks are happening when you "play" notes that don't exist.  As to why, could be faulty wiring ... but who knows.

Comment: Agreed. I've gone through 2 guitars this way. Once they start double-strumming, they're fairly useless.

Comment: +1 for the double strum answer, when my guitar started doing this I took the faceplate off and sprayed some WD40 into and around the strumbar. This actually fixed the problem for a little while for me ... not saying its the best idea for everyone but its always there as an option.

Comment: Oh dear... is there any way it can be fixed?